# Generate a single model in Railroad?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the railroad gem, and I can generate an entire map of my application just fine - but I'd like to generate associations for just a single model, is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this fork (that has my commits to enable specifying models)

https://github.com/tobias/RailRoad
(install with gem install tobias-railroad)

Then you can just add

```
--specify app/models/user.rb
```

to your railroad command to plot a single model's associations